# scroll clistviewctrl in wtl, when new item is added

Tags: c++, winapi, listview, wtl

I want to scroll to the end of the listview, when a new item is added. I'm using CListViewCtrl from WTL. Here is my function for adding a new item and scrolling:

```
void CMainDlg::addMessage(CString msg)
{
    m_wndList.InsertItem ( n++, msg);
    SIZE size;
    size.cx = 0;
    size.cy = n;
    m_wndList.Scroll(size);
}
```

`n` is just a global variable:

```
int n = 0;
```

The function works, aside from not scrolling at all.

I've looked at the source for `Scroll` in wtl and it looks fine:

```
BOOL Scroll(SIZE size)
{
        ATLASSERT(::IsWindow(m_hWnd));
        return (BOOL)::SendMessage(m_hWnd, LVM_SCROLL, size.cx, size.cy);
}
```

So why isn't it scrolling? I've tried `n+1`, etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, you scroll by pixels. Use the `EnsureVisible` function instead (it sends `LVM_ENSUREVISIBLE`).